# Echo out key and value from array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array called $topProductIdResults and it looks like the following:

```
Array ( [11497522] => 2  )
```

The keys are prodcuct ID's and the value is the number of 5 star ratings that the product has recieved.

I want it to echo out this data using a loop. However I can't work our how to echo out both the key and value. Sometimes there will be several product ID's and number pairs in this array. Please let me know where I'm going wrong. My code so far is:

```
foreach ($topProductIdResults as $prod) {
    echo $prod[0];
    echo $prod[1];
}
```

which just echo's 22 at the moment. I want it to echo 11497522 2

Comment: You're accessing only the values of the hash.  In order to traverse both the keys & values, you need something like: `foreach($hash as $key => $value)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
foreach ($topProductIdResults as $key => $value) {
    echo $key;
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
foreach ($topProductIdResults as $key=>$prod) {
    echo $key;
    echo $prod;
}
```

Ref: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

If you just have a single dimensional array with key and value `Array ( [11497522] => 2  )` , then you can use this :

```
$array   = array(11497522=>2);
$key     = key($array);
$value   = $array[$key];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
 foreach ($topProductIdResults  as $key => $value)
 {
     echo $key;
     echo $value;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 foreach ($topProductIdResults as $prodid => $prod) {
    echo $prod[0];
    echo $prod[1];
}
```